# Insert blank row in the postgres query result

Tags: postgresql

I have below table after run a postgres query `select * from tbl`

```
1 type_1 name-1
2 type_1 name_2
3 type_2 name_3
4 type_2 name_4
5 type_3 name_5
```

how can I add a blank line in between each type so I can read the output easily?

Like

```
1 type_1 name-1
2 type_1 name_2

3 type_2 name_3
4 type_2 name_4

5 type_3 name_5
```

OR

```
1 type_1 name-1
2 type_1 name_2
- ----   ----
3 type_2 name_3
4 type_2 name_4
- ----   ----
5 type_3 name_5
```

Comment: That very much depends on the tool you use to execute the queries. But in any case that's job for the code on the client side.

Comment: I am doing it in the Postgres console, no php or other tools available...

Comment: Ah, `psql`. I gather you've consulted [the fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) already?

Comment: You write `between each type`. Do you mean "between each row"? And why is the separating row missing for *some* rows in your example? Also, provide your table definition (`\d tbl` in psql) and Postgres version.

Comment: I added a solution for your clarified question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Spacer between all rows

`UNION ALL` with the same query and blank columns. The only purpose of the subquery is to hide the additional column `rn`, which I use for sorting.

```
SELECT tbl_id, type, name
FROM  (
   SELECT tbl_id AS rn, tbl_id, type, name
   FROM   tbl

   UNION  ALL
   SELECT tbl_id AS rn, NULL::int, NULL::text, NULL::text
   FROM   tbl
   OFFSET 1
   )
ORDER BY rn, tbl_id NULLS FIRST
```

`OFFSET 1` in combination with the later `NULLS FIRST`  in `ORDER BY` avoids a dangling spacer.

#### Spacer between groups of rows

Answer to updated question:

```
SELECT tbl_id, type, name
FROM  (
   SELECT type AS rn, tbl_id, type, name
   FROM   tbl

   UNION  ALL
   SELECT DISTINCT type AS rn, NULL::int, NULL::text, NULL::text
   FROM   tbl
   OFFSET 1
   )
ORDER BY rn, type NULLS FIRST
```